# STL multimap associative containers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does anyone know how to create two multimap associative containers. The first one would have duplicate keys. Then i would like to post the algorithm to search for all duplicates and move them over to a second container and maybe delete the original duplicates in the first container.

i.e. :

```
typedef multimap< int, int, less< int > > mma;
mma contain1;

typedef multimap< int, less< int > > ne;
ne contain2;

cointain1.insert(mma::value_tpe(5, 2);
cointain1.insert(mma::value_tpe(5, 3);
cointain1.insert(mma::value_tpe(5, 3);
cointain1.insert(mma::value_tpe(6, 2);
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about `multi_map::lower_bound` and `multi_map::upper_bound`. They'll give you a pair of iterators that define a sequence of values that are equal to the argument. If the length of the sequence is greater than 1, you've got duplicates.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I do some research on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you iterate over the first multimap, looking for duplicates.  When you find them, you move them to the second multimap.

```
typedef multimap<int, int> mma;
mma contain1;
mma contain2;

contain1.insert(mma::value_type(5, 2);
contain1.insert(mma::value_type(5, 3);
contain1.insert(mma::value_type(5, 3);
contain1.insert(mma::value_type(6, 2); 

int previous;

for (mma::iterator i = contain1.begin(); i != contain1.end(); )
    if (i != contain1.begin() && i->first == previous)
    {
        contain2[i->first] = i->second;

        // "maybe delete the original duplicates in the first container"...
        contain1.erase(i++);
    }
    else
    {
        previous = i->first;
        ++i;
    }
```